# Why does Windows Media Player prevent changing playback speed only on certain files and not others?

Tags: windows, video, windows-media-player

I would really like to have this capability for all media types.  It seems like it allows it for .mp4 files but not for certain .mkvs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because Windows Media Player uses a Media Foundation-based codec for MP4 files, but a DirectShow-based codec for MKV. If you find an Media Foundation MKV codec, you should also be able to change the playback speed there.